# Move more elements with same class in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code and I want to move the 'a' tag on top of the two parents (other-div and some-other-div)

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-other-div">
    <div class="other-div">
      <a class="link" href="#">move me<a>
    </div>
      </div>
    <div class="some-other-div">
      <div class="other-div">
        <a class="link" href="#">move me<a>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

To look like this

```
<div class="container">
   <a class="link" href="#">move me<a>
  <div class="some-other-div">
    <div class="other-div">

    </div>
      </div>
      <a class="link" href="#">move me<a>
    <div class="some-other-div">
      <div class="other-div">

      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is a pen I've created:

http://codepen.io/florinsimion/pen/qqRWOo

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`before()`](http://api.jquery.com/before/#before-function) method with a callback function which iterates over the elements and inside the callback return the `a` tag to be moved.

```js
$('.some-other-div').before(function() {
  return $(this).find('.link');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-other-div">
    <div class="other-div">
      <a class="link" href="#">move me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="some-other-div">
    <div class="other-div">
      <a class="link" href="#">move me</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you...that did the job.

Comment: @FlorinSimion :  glad to help :)